# Assigning python lambda functions in a loop rather than explicitly

Tags: python-3.x, loops, lambda

I currently have a function inside a class that roughly look like so:

```
    class myclass:
        @staticmethod
        def method():
            A = lambda a: a
            B = lambda A,a,c: f(a)+g(A)+c
            C = lambda B,a,c: f(a)+g(B)+c
            D = lambda C,a,c: f(a)+g(C)+c


            return OrderedDict([("A", A), ("B", B), ("C", C), ("D", D)])
```

For each variable, I am calling the same type of lambda function (a lot of other stuff is happening inside the lambda function but that's irrelevant for this question). The return is an ordered dictionary that is necessitated by how this function is used.

Is there no easier way of writing this function? The lambda function is always the same but the inputs to it differ.

I would like to place the variable assignments in a loop but all lambda function calls depend on the previous variable (e.g. `B` depends on the output of `A`).

So something like:

```
for var in [A, B, C, D]:
    if var == A:
       # Assign special lambda function
    else:
       var = lambda previous_value, a, c: f(a)+g(previous_value)+c
```

Not sure how to do this. Pointers would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def method() -> Dict[str, Callable]:
        def create_lambda(previous_value: Callable) -> Callable:
           return lambda a, c: f(a)+g(previous_value)+c
        
        callable = lambda a: a
        functions: Dict[str, Callable] = {}
        for name in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'):
            functions[name] = callable
            callable = create_lambda(callable)
        return functions
```

If you want to actually create a callable (either a `lambda` or just `def`) inside a loop move the callable creation out into another function. That way you have full control over it: in particular the previous callable is a bound variable so you need a new scope to bind it.